# NSFetchRequest different result compared to 'findAll'

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using CoreData and can retrieve my objects using `[MyManagedObjectClass findAll]`. Now I want to fetch some Data using an `NSFetchRequest` which looks like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Although I don't have a predicate, the request does not return all the objects but 0 objects instead. AFAIK I don't need to have a predicate, if I want to load all the objects, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was not using the same context as core data. If I get the context from the CoreData object then it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Although I don't have a predicate, the request does not return all the
>   objects but 0 objects instead. AFAIK I don't need to have a predicate,
>   if I want to load all the objects, right?

right

- self.context is not nil ?
- NSError is empty after the request ?

Comment: They both seem to be ok: self.context is initialized and the error is nil

Comment: and you are sure to have entities "Contacts" actually in your database ?

Comment: self.context was not nil, but it was the wrong context. See my own answer